# How to provide two forms using ModelDriven in Struts 2

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, model-driven

I have this code to implement `ModelDriven` mechanism.

```
public class Input_newAction extends CommonAction implements ModelDriven<InputForm> {

    private InputForm form = new InputForm();
    @Override
    public InputForm getModel() {
        return form;
    }
}
```

The problem is I need to pass another form to `Input_newAction`. How to do this?

```
public class Input_newAction extends CommonAction implements ModelDriven<InputForm>, 
ModelDriven<CopyForm> {
...
}
```

Comment: i do not think this is possible (not 100% sure). either you can have nested object with one domain object or can use simple object mapping in place of model driven.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot implement two or more *specialization* of the same interface.

Instead you could make an interface or abstract class for the forms that will specialize the `ModelDriven` and return that interface via implementing `getModel()` of the `ModelDriven`.

When the action is called you could check some condition (either parameter or method, or mapping) and return the corresponding model to fit the condition specified.

```
public class Input_newAction extends CommonAction implements ModelDriven<CommonForm> {
  private boolean par;
  public setPar(boolean par){
    this.par = par;
  } 

  @Override
  public CommonForm getModel() {
    if (par)
     return inputForm;  
    else
     return copyForm;
  }
}
```